# How can I remove Git from Flutter project on VSCode?

Tags: git, flutter, visual-studio-code, version-control

I have a project that I want to remove git from, but simply deleting the .git file breaks the project. I get this error if I do that:
`The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.`

I had to reinstall Flutter to fix this, and when I reinstalled the project had git again. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the project in the Project Explorer panel and then choose Source Control > Delete Repository from the context menu.

Answer (score 2):

Run this command `rm -rf .git*`.

Answer (score 0):

**From VSCode Terminal:**

*Inside Project run this command*

```
 rm -fr .git
```

**Verify the git repo. exists**

```
git status
//fatal: not a git repository
```